# chngcntr package works for first chapter but not for other chapters of book

Tags: tables, numbering, chngcntr

The package:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{}
```

Works for the first chapter of my thesis, but on the two other chapters, the count starts at every section, I don't know why it's not working for the next chapters.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part} %To reset chapter counter for every part
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
}
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true, 
     citecolor    = blue
}
% \usepackage{hypertex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\addbibresource{inf.bib}
\addbibresource{aid.bib}
\addbibresource{csr.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{alltt}

\doublespacing

\restylefloat{figure}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[lmargin=3.20cm,rmargin=3.0cm,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm]{geometry}

% Set the beginning of a LaTeX document
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.3}
\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\newpage
\mainmatter
\chapter{Ilkfo}
\label{Chapter 1} 

\begin{doublespace}
\section{Introduction}
Text....

\section{Literature review}
\subparagraph{Background...}

This section.....

%%%%%%
%Table 1
\begin{table} [htbp]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab1}
\textbf{Summar...}}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Mean}  & \textbf{Std. Dev.} & \textbf{Min.} &  \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{Obs.}\\ \hline  
\cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{6}{l}   {Panel A: } \\ \hline
Age &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{6}{l}     {Panel B: } \\ \hline 
Age  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}     {Panel C: } \\ \hline 
Age &  &  &  &  & \\
\cline{1-6}
\end{tabular} 
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
%%%%%%

\section{Results}
\subsection{... results}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Table 5: Main regression results

\begin{table} [htbp]
\centering
\caption{\label{general}
\textbf{Ma...}}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \toprule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{ \emph{Infor}} \\ \hline  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Full sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{txt} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text} \\
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) \\  
  \midrule
 & & & & & & & \\
textx & *** &  &  & ** &  & - &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes} \footnotesize \item Notes: text 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{doublespace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\newpage
\begin{subappendices} 
\section{Quarterly...}

\begin{table} [htbp]
\centering
\caption{\label{quarterlytransitions}
\textbf{text}}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l c c }\hline 
\textbf{Change} & \textbf{$Formal_{t}$}  & \textbf{$Informal_{t}$} \\ \hline  
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{3}{l} {Panel A: } \\ \hline
$Informal_{t-1}$ & \% & \% \\  \hline   
\cline{1-3} 
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{subappendices}

\backmatter
\pagebreak

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagebreak
\mainmatter
\chapter{Latin American...}
\label{Chapter 2} 

\begin{doublespace}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{table} [htbp]
\caption{\label{sumstatisticsaid}
\textbf{Summary }}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c  c c }\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\underline{\textbf{ World}}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\underline{\textbf{Latin }}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable} & Mean  & Obs. & Mean & Obs.\\ 
 \hline
 &&&& \\
Ln per capita Income (US\$ constant) &    &  &    & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes} \footnotesize \item Sta
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\section{Methodology}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Table 1. MAIN SPECIFICATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table} [htbp]
\caption{\label{mainaid}
\textbf{Aid }}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc} \hline
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{$ Aid$}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$d)$}  \\
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
 \hline
 &&&& \\
 &  &  &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes} \footnotesize \item ade. 
\item Notes: el. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{doublespace}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

The table of contents looks something like this:
1 Chapter 1
    1.1 Introduction . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    1.2 Literature review . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    1.3 Methodology . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
            1.3.1 Conceptual  . . . . . 12
            1.3.2 Empirical . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 16
    1.4 Data  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 19
        1.4.1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
        1.4.2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 21
Appendices 46
    1.A  . . . . . . . 46
    1.B  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 46

2 Chapter 2
    2.1 Introduction . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    2.2 Literature Review . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .. . .
    2.3 Data . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    2.4 Methodology . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 [image: example of table of contents]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/331271/edit) your post and add a small complete LaTeX document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows your problem.

Comment: Hi @gernot, I just managed to edit the text to that shows the problem.

Comment: Can you explain how the structure of your document should look like? Don't use LaTeX commands for this, just sketch the table of contents: numbering, indentation, etc. Your LaTeX code is confusing: You say `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}`, but you don't use `\part` commands. It is also unclear to me, whether appendices are on the level of chapters or sections; and I guess, you don't want to have the appendices numbered within the preceding chapter.

Comment: Add the information to your post, using the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/331271/edit).

Comment: The appendices are not numbered within the preceding chapter and are at the level of chapters.

Comment: @gernot I added a picture of the table of contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to use the `appendix` package (to have better control over what happens; otherwise you have to undo again the things that you don't like). Moreover, use `\mainmatter` only once, because otherwise it will reset again the page counter. If you like a specific side-effect of the second `\mainmatter`, let's achieve it explicitly.

Below is a sample document that seems to produce what you want. Let me know if anything is missing. Copy the definition of the environment `appendices`, remove `\numberwithin{table}{chapter}` (this is the default), remove `\usepackage{appendix}`, remove `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}` (you don't have `\part`s), remove `\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{}`, and remove the whole `\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}` stuff.

As a side-note, except from exceptional cases, the package `hyperref` should be loaded last. Moreover, you load several packages twice (`booktabs`, `caption`), and I'm not convinced that you really need `adjustbox`, `float` and several other of the packages. You also have a duplicate `\restylefloat{table}`. You declare `\doublespacing` in the preamble, but set `\setstretch{1.3}` later in the document. Usually it is better not to collect preambles from different documents and web pages without having a good reason.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newenvironment{appendices}%
  {\chapter*{Appendices}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}%
   \setcounter{section}{0}%
   \def\thesection{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}%
   \counterwithin{figure}{section}%
   \counterwithin{table}{section}%
  }%
  {\counterwithout{figure}{section}%
   \counterwithout{table}{section}%
  }

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\somecontents
  {\lipsum[1]
   \begin{table}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{cc}
       a & b \\
       c & d
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{Some caption}
     \label{tab:\thetable}
   \end{table}
   \lipsum[2]
  }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Informality and Taxes in Mexico}
\section{Introduction}
\somecontents
\section{Literature review}
\somecontents
\section{Methodology}
\somecontents
\subsection{Conceptual framework and threats to identification}
\somecontents
\subsection{Empirical stratecy and specification}
\somecontents

\begin{appendices}
\section{Quaterly transitions between formality and informality}
\somecontents
\somecontents
\section{Formulas to calculate average tax rates}
\somecontents
\somecontents
\section{Narrative discussion of changes in tax rates}
\somecontents
\somecontents
\end{appendices}

\chapter{Latin American Aid Patterns: Democratic Political Regimes and US domestic Politics}
\section{Introduction}
\somecontents
\section{Literature review}
\somecontents
\section{Data}
\somecontents
\section{Methodology}
\somecontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! I also removed everything else you mentioned!!! Thanks a lot! Now I can finally submit the last version!! :)

Comment: @user95256 To indicate that the solution worked for you, please tick the check mark to its left. Otherwise it looks like an unresolved issue. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) for an explanation.